# How to Prevent Inno Setup adding files multiple times when creating an installer and portable extractor

Tags: delphi, installation, pascal

I like to create installer / portable extractors in one setup and sometimes i use .paf portables, i use a check inside the [Code] section so the installer knows where to place files depending if install or portable and that works perfectly but the installer keeps adding the files 2x due to the way i do it. I am wondering if there is a simple way to stop Inno Setup from adding files multiple times and causing a large installer.

Example script:

```
[Files]
;Install for x64 & x86
    Source: "{app}\shared\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: not InstallType('Portable');
    Source: "{app}\x64\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: isWin64 and not InstallType('Portable');
    Source: "{app}\x86\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: not isWin64 and not InstallType('Portable');
    
    ;Portable.PAF
    ;Source: "AppPortable.PAF\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; check: InstallType('Portable')
    Source: "AppPortable.PAF\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: InstallType('Portable');
    Source: "{app}\shared\*"; DestDir: "{app}\App\ProgramFiles64"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: InstallType('Portable');
    Source: "{app}\shared\*"; DestDir: "{app}\App\ProgramFiles"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: InstallType('Portable');
    Source: "{app}\x64\*"; DestDir: "{app}\App\ProgramFiles64"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: InstallType('Portable');
    Source: "{app}\x86\*"; DestDir: "{app}\App\ProgramFiles"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: InstallType('Portable');
```

I have tried something like this with no luck:

```
#If  "not InstallType('Portable')"
Source: "{app}\x64";  DestDir: "{code:GetExeLocation}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: not InstallType('Portable')
Source: "{app}\x86\*"; DestDir: "{code:GetExeLocation}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: not InstallType('Portable')
#Else
Source: "{app}\x64\*"; DestDir: "{code:GetExeLocation}\App\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;; Check: InstallType('Portable')
Source: "{app}\x86\*"; DestDir: "{code:GetExeLocation}\App\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;; Check: InstallType('Portable')
#EndIf
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a file that is added twice? And where it is located in your source directories? As far as I know, the files section of InnoSetup does not add things twice just because you have listed them twice for both install types.

Comment: Every file is added twice. From all of the source directories
{app}\shared, {app}\x64 and {app}\x86. Each one contains multiple files and they are all added twice because the portable path is silghtly different so needs to be written under [files] section twice. Once for install path and once for portable path

Comment: Try using another Variable which you change to the destination you actually want instead of adding files more than once.

Comment: Could you show me an example im not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: Notice a lot of `recursesubdirs` so make sure the you aren't including a higher level folder that has the others already.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are actually duplicates in your source folders then they will be added twice. This is intended (and desired) behaviour of InnoSetup. You can have multiple files with the same source, but with different destinations.

Make sure each file that is shared between the 2 different installation types is  added from the same source directory. InnoSetup should then add the same file only once.

Comment: The files are not duplicates, they are only in the source folders once. Ive done exactly what you have suggested. The files shared between both installation types come from the same source file but they keep getting added twice. I also thought inno didnt duplicate but it does. Ive tried multiple times, as long as the same source file is listed more than once it seems so ignore the install type and add it anyway.